# Which game company should I choose (UE4 vs Unity)

Tags: job-offer, job-change, gaming

I am considering a programmer's job in two game companies. Company A does small to medium sized PC games in UE4, Company B - free to play mobile games in Unity.

Considering I want to stay in game development for as long as I can, possibly until I retire, and I am afraid of my skills becoming obsolete - is it more beneficial to choose Company A because they make more "real" games? Or is it better to go for the free-to-play mobile market, because it is bigger?

Comment: I would suggest going with the company you think *you’d enjoy making games for.* Ftp games are often vampiric in nature and design...often taking advantage of the pay to win model...while ‘classic’ games usually don’t follow the same path. And is so far still around even though mobile gaming has stormed the casual market...which wains a lot. I am not comfortable in the ftp industry, and wouldnt work for them taking advantage of gambling habits and ptw models. However this is solely an opinion based comment, and i doubt you’ll find answers that are purely objective.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question may be too reliant on opinion. Change happens quickly in the game industry, and there is no way to predict what the industry will be like by the time you retire.

Suppose someone started their first job as a programmer at 25 years old and is retiring this year (2019) at 65. That person got into the industry in 1979. There is little that has not changed in these past 40 years.

In my opinion, questions such as yours should be regarded on no more than a 5-year timescale. Sources such as the [StackOverflow Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019) - or discussions with people that work in the industry - can be used to make a more informed decision. It will most likely not be a perfect decision, and you will likely make a few choices that you, with 20/20 hindsight, would not make again - even if you do not regret them outright.